# Installing auto-complete in emacs

Tags: emacs

I am a new to Emacs , i downloaded auto-complete , moved it to ~/.emacs.d/plugins/ then modified the .emacs file to look like :

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (file-name-as-directory
                     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-complete"))\
)

(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)

(ac-config-default)
(custom-set-variables
;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.                                   
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                       
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                           
'(menu-bar-mode nil)
'(package-archives (quote (("melpa" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") ("g\
nu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(custom-set-faces
;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.                                       
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                       
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                           
)
```

when i restart emacs , it displays the following error :

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/zeaksilva/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, auto-complete

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is on-topic here or not, but it seems like it might be more appropriate on [emacs.se].

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: Why wouldn't it be on topic here (also)? Now we have the [same question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3306/105) in two places. Not helpful, IMHO. If you want to migrate it from here to there (which I do not think is called for), then do that. At least that doesn't lead to duplication of the question and scattering of answers.

Comment: Why are you manually downloading and trying to install `auto-complete` when it is much easier to install using an third-party ELPA repository (like Marmalade, which you already appear to be using)?

Comment: Your code looks OK, so the problem probably doesn't have anything to do with emacs. Are there any typos in the file name? Does the file to load end with .el or .elc? Can you (load ...) the file manually? (You know you can execute an emacs lisp expression by moving the cursor behind it and pressing C-x C-e )

Answer (score 0):

Put `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the beginning of your init file. Or better yet, append `--debug-init` to the command line you use to invoke Emacs. That will open the debugger when the error occurs. But it seems that the file that has `(provide 'autocomplete)` in it, or that file's directory, is not in your `load-path`. When the debugger opens, use `C-h v load-path`, and see whether it is correct.

And try commenting out all of the extra stuff in your init file, which does not seem related to this problem: the `custom-set-variables` and `custom-set-faces`. IOW, simplify the sack of stuff that you try to debug.